# Solvability of $A X B=C$ with $X=X^\mathrm{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-inverse

I am studying symmetric solutions to the complex matrix equation
\begin{equation}
A X B=C,
\end{equation}
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $m\times n$, $n \times k$, and $m \times k$ complex matrices, respectively. We may further assume that these matrices are arbitrary random unstructured matrices (i.e., any submatrix of $A$, $B$, or $C$ is full-rank with probability 1). Furthermore, $X$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of unknowns, which is restricted to be symmetric (i.e., $X$=$X^\mathrm{T}$). I would like to find (and prove) a rule for obtaining the minimum $n$ that allows for a solution to this equation.

When trying to solve this problem by vectorizing, I reach a linear equation like
\begin{equation}
(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}v=\mathrm{vec}(C),
\end{equation}
where $Z_U$ and $Z_D$ are matrices selecting and permuting the elements of $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)$ associated to the upper and lower triangular parts of $X$, respectively, and $v$ is the $n(n+1)/2$-sized vector of unique unknowns. We further know that $Z_D = K^{(n,n)}Z_U$, where $K^{(n,n)}$ is the respective conmutation matrix. What I have noticed is that the matrix $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}$, and specifically $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)(I+K^{(n,n)})$ where $I$ stands for identity matrix, may have rank lower than $mk$ even when $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)$ has rank $mk$ (and $n(n+1)/2>mk$). I feel like there should be a way to predict how the rank of said product of matrices behaves, but I have failed to characterize it. We may also formulate this problem in terms of characterizing the right-invertibility of $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}$.

Another empirical observation I noted is that, for the square case where $m=k$, the solvability of this equation is given by the simple rule $n=2m-1$, but I am not able to prove even this case.

**Edit:** When $\mathrm{rank}\left((B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}\right)=mk$ the solution is trivially given by applying the pseudo-inverse $(.)^\dagger$ as $$v=\left((B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}\right)^\dagger \mathrm{vec}(C),$$ and remapping $v$ to the symmetric matrix structure, but the question is about how to know if there is a solution or not. Specifically, about what values of $n$ assure solvability.

**Edit 2:** By empirical evaluation for the general case it seems that the solvability of this equation is given by the simple rule $n\geq m+k-1$. However, I would still like to find a formal proof to this rule, which I have failed to do so far.

Comment: I reposted this question at [math.stackexchange_link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851009/solvability-of-a-x-b-c-with-x-x-mathrmt) since I was not 100% sure where it would fit best. Comments in this respect are appreciated. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $U^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of $U$.

Assume that $A,B,C$ are generic; there exists a solution $U$ of $AU_{n,k}=C$ only if $AA^+C=C$.

This -generically- never happens unless $AA^+=I_m$, that is, when $n\geq m$.
In the same way, there exists -generically- a solution $V$ of $V_{m,n}B=C$ only when $n\geq k$. In the sequel, we assume these 2 conditions are satisfied.

Consider the following example: $m=4,n=8,k=3$.

If we stack the matrices row by row, then $X\mapsto AXB$ is associated to the matrix $A\otimes B^T$. This last matrix has rank $mk=12$ and is surjective. The dimension of the affine space $R$ of all solutions of $AXB=C$ is $n^2-mk=8^2-12=52$. Now $S$ -the vector space of symmetric matrices- has dimension $n(n+1)/2=36$; -generically- the spaces $R,S$ (affine subspaces of $M_8$ of dimension $n^2=64$) are transverse.
Finally, the space of symmetric solutions satisfies $dim(R\cap S)=dim(R)+dim(S)-dim(M_8)=n(n+1)/2-mk=24$.

Beware,if you want to be sure that there are symmetric solutions, then you have to assume $n(n+1)/2>mk$. For example, when $m=5,n=5,k=3$, generically there are no symmetric solutions.

$\textbf{EDIT 1}$ In fact, in addition to the conditions $n\geq m,n\geq k$,the condition $n(n+1)/2>mk$ is not sufficient. It seems that, as @Juan wrote above, that the good extra condition is $n\geq m+k-1$. For example:

$\bullet$ when $m=6,n=9,k=4$ ($n=m+k-1$), $dim(R\cap S)=n(n+1)/2-mk=21$.

$\bullet$ when $m=6,n=9,k=5$ ($n=m+k-2$), there are no symmetric solutions although $n(n+1)/2-mk=15$...

$\textbf{EDIT 2}$ $\textbf{Proposition.}$ Generically, there is a symmetric matrix solution if and only if $n\geq m,n\geq k,n\geq m+k-1$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ $\bullet$ Assume that $m\leq k$.

Let $E_k=im(B)$ and $F_m$ be s.t. $\ker(A)_{n-m}\oplus F_m=\mathbb{C}^n$. $A$ is a bijection from $F_m$ to $im(C)$ and $X_{|E_k}$ is a fixed surjection onto $F_m$. Generically, $E_k$ anf $F_m$ are transverse.

If we want to extend $X_{|E_k}$ into a symmetric matrix $X$, then the submatrix associated with $X_{|E_k}$  must not cross (strictly) the diagonal of the large matrix reserved for $X$. Then $n\geq m+k-1$ and $dim(E_k\cap F_m)=1$ in the limit case (to see that, place the submatrix at the top right of the matrix reserved for $X$).

$\bullet$ If $k\leq m$, then note that $B^TXA^T=C^T$ admits a symmetric solution; the roles of $k,m$ are exchanged. Then we obtain again the condition $n\geq m+k-1$.

$\textbf{Conclusion.}$ If the above conditions are satisfied, then the set of symmetric solutions is an affine space of dimension $n(n+1)/2-mk$; otherwise, there are no symmetric solutions.

$\textbf{Answer to Juan's comment.}$ $\bullet$ If $n=m+k-1,m\leq k$ -for example $n=20,m=9,k=12$- then $dim(E_k\cap F_m)=1$ and that works.

Note that a symmetric matrix remains symmetric after a permutation of the elements of a basis. Thus we may assume that $e_1,\cdots,e_9$ is a basis of $F_m$ and $e_9,\cdots,e_{20}$ is a basis of $E_k$. The top right $9\times 12$ submatrix $S$ associated to $X_{|E_k}$ intersects the diagonal of $X$ only in $(9,9)$. Then we can complete the submatrix $S$ into a symmetric one.

$\bullet$ if $n=m+k-2,m\leq k$ -for example $n=20,m=10,k=12$- then $dim(E_k\cap F_m)=2$ and that doesn't work.

Here $e_1,\cdots,e_{10}$ is a basis of $F_m$. The top right $10\times 12$ submatrix $S$ intersects the diagonal in $(9,9)$ and $(10,10)$ and has an entry below the diagonal: $S_{10,9}$. Since, generically $S_{9,10}\not= S_{10,9}$, we cannot complete the submatrix into a symmetric one.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the concept of transversability, but is it possible that $R$ and $S$ are not generically transverse due to the structure of the problem? If so, do you think this could be actually proven? It does make much sense that if the dimension of $dim(R\cap S)$ is greater than 1 there is no solution does it.

Comment: Correction on my previous comment: "It doesn't make much sense..."

Comment: That's great progress for sure! I still fail to see how the "only if" statement is justified though, cause if $dim(E_k \cap F_m)\geq 1$, how can you be sure that there is no 
symmetric solution that doesn't require such symetric extension?